# Reverse for 'edit_comment' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/edit_comment/(?P<id>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django

Не открывается страница редактирования комментария. Выдает ошибку `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit_comment' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/edit_comment/(?P<id>[^/]+)/\\Z']`

Вот вью:

```
class AddCommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = AddComment
    form_class = AddCommentForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
    template_name = 'blog/comment.html'
    post_date = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = get_object_or_404(AddComment, pk=kwargs['id'])
        if instance.author != request.user:
            return redirect('blog:post_detail', pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Модель

```
class AddComment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField('Текст комментария')
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comment',
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
```

Урлы

```
    path('posts/<pk>/edit_comment/<id>/',
         views.AddCommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit_comment'),
```

Шаблон. Он без изменений. И его менять не нужно. Т.е. проблемы там по идее не должно быть

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}
{% block title %}
  {% if '/edit_comment/' in request.path %}
    Редактирование комментария
  {% else %}
    Удаление комментария
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 40rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
          {% if '/edit_comment/' in request.path %}
            Редактирование комментария
          {% else %}
            Удаление комментария
          {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form method="post"
            {% if '/edit_comment/' in request.path %}
              action="{% url 'blog:edit_comment' comment.post_id comment.id %}"
            {% endif %}>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if not '/delete_comment/' in request.path %}
              {% bootstrap_form form %}
            {% else %}
              <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% bootstrap_button button_type="submit" content="Отправить" %}
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```